# I did a dumb and deleted /usr/lib32

Tags: pacman, 32bit, artix-linux

Today I was having trouble with steam. It wanted some libraries that I didn't have, so I tried to install the steam-native-runtime on my system (I run Artix, basically Arch) and it was yelling about systemd and eudev and elogind or something. My system uses OpenRC, so I figure "I dont even have systemd what are you doing?" And since my system is yelling about lib32, I think "I have a 64-bit system, I'll just delete em' and reinstall."

I still haven't managed to reinstall my lib32 files, and I'm afraid if I power off my system it wont start again. Send help.

Comment: By the time you figure out how to fix everything - if it's even possible at this point - you could have reinstalled the system. Trust your data backups and start over.

Comment: @ajgringo619 but I could just reinstall everything from the pacman cache? I don't exactly know how I would do that, but I know it should be possible?

Comment: It *might* work, but a complete reinstall *will* work. As long as your data backups are complete, this should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by reinstalling all the packages from my pacman cache. Here's the script I used, and credit to Mefju from the [Arch Linux BBS](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=34832) for making the script!

Here's the script, by the way:

```
#! /bin/sh

for pkg in $(pacman -Q | cut -d' ' -f1); do
    pacman -S --noconfirm $pkg
done
```